# Methods and sub-methods in JS object literals

Tags: javascript, oop, object, object-literal

So if I declare an object in Javascript like so:

```
var myhouse = {
    room: {
        bed: function() { return "sleep"; }
    }
}
```

I can call:

```
myhouse.room.bed();
```

Can I make a method that's callable with just:

```
myhouse.room();
```

? I can't just say:

```
var myhouse = {
    room: {
        function() { return "stuff"; },
        bed: function() { return "sleep"; }
    }
}
```

It's invalid. So what am I missing? Is it even a good idea to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with just object literals, you can do it "manually" however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with a single literal, you need an extra assignment to set a property on a function:

```
var myhouse = {
    room: function() { return "stuff"; }
};
myhouse.room.bed = function() { return "sleep"; };
```

To make it a single expression, you could either use a IEFE

```
var myhouse = {
    room: (function(){
        var room = room = function() { return "stuff"; }
        room.bed = function() { return "sleep"; };
        return room;
    })()
};
```

or the comma operator (horribly unreadable, but working):

```
var myhouse = {
    // using myhouse as an already declared variable
    room: (myhouse = function() {return "stuff";},
           myhouse.bed = function() {return "sleep";},
           myhouse)
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That first one does it for me but the others are great to know, even if they do twist my head a bit! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use such syntax if you know that function is object too.

```
var room = function() { return "stuff"; }
room.bed = function() { return "sleep"; };

var myhouse = { room: room };
myhouse.room(); // stuff
myhouse.room.bed(); // sleep
```

Or

```
var myhouse = { room: function() { return "stuff"; } };
myhouse.room.bed = function() { return "sleep"; };
myhouse.room(); // stuff
myhouse.room.bed(); // sleep
```